# how to rebase between two git repositories

Tags: git

we have two remote repositories for same project origin and sandbox.Now i am in origin master branch and trying to pull sandbox feature branch but i am getting conflict issue.

So how should i rebase my sandbox feature branch on origin master branch? 
and this is a regular thing so what is the best practice to resolve conflicts in this case?
Note: i have already checked similar questions like
[How to rebase one Git repository onto another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428137/how-to-rebase-one-git-repository-onto-another-one)
[How to rebase one repo to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247487/how-to-rebase-one-repo-to-another)

Comment: Why can't you just resolve the conflicts?

Comment: merge conflict will add extra commit and i didn't want to send extra commit to gerrit server

Comment: I don't get any merge commits when resolving conflicts during rebase.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your `origin` repo. Add a new remote with `sandbox` URL. Then rebase `sandbox/feature` branch into `origin/master` branch. Then if conflict occurs resolve it.

```
# go into your origin repo
$ git checkout master
$ git remote add sandbox <sanbox-repo-url>
$ git fetch sandbox

$ git rebase sandbox/feature
```

If Conflict occurs, then better resolve conflicts manually. You can also accept `origin` or `sandbox` changes by `--theirs` or `--ours` flag.

```
$ git status        # see the conflicted files (red color)

# resolve conflicts
$ git checkout --theirs <file-name>    # accept origin changes
Or,
$ git checkout --ours <file-name>      # accept sandbox changes
```